# Differentiating current textbox value from old one and showing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
<body>
<div>
    <table ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="prdElement in palletElement track by $index">
            <tr>
                <td>{{prdElement.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in prdElement.Data">
                <td>{{data.itemId}}</td>
                <td>{{data.shipmentId}}</td>
                <td>{{data.itemCode}}</td>
                <td>{{data.description}}</td>
                <td>{{data.handlingUnit}}</td>
                <td>{{data.weight}}</td>
                <td>{{data.class}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lenght}}</td>
                <td>{{data.width}}</td>
                <td>{{data.height}}</td>
                <td>{{data.flag}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="data.quantity" placeholder=" Code" required />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="newPalletItem( prdElement,$event)">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!--<tr id="displayitems" >
                <td>
                    {{palletElement}}
                </td>
             
            </tr>-->

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
    (function () {
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

        var counter = 0;

        $scope.palletElement = [{
            name: 'Pallet 1',
            Data: [{
                name: 'item 1',
                itemId: '284307',
                shipmentId: 'eb44f690-c97a-40e3-be2a-0449559e171a',
                itemCode: '',
                description: 'Bicycle parts - frame',
                quantity: '31',
                handlingUnit: 'CTN',
                weight: '613.04',
                class: '',
                lenght: '102',
                width: '42',
                height: '61',
                flag: 'P'

            }, {
                name: 'item 2',
                itemId: '284308',
                shipmentId: 'eb44f690-c97a-40e3-be2a-0449559e171a',
                itemCode: '',
                description: 'Bicycle parts - fork',
                quantity: '22',
                handlingUnit: 'CTN',
                weight: '242.99',
                class: '',
                lenght: '75',
                width: '34',
                height: '18',
                flag: 'P'
            }]
        }]

        $scope.newPalletItem = function (palletElement, $event) {
            counter++;
            $scope.palletElement.push(palletElement);
        }

    });
}());
```

When some one changes the value in last column textbox and press submit button I want to calculate [preloded value in textbox - (minus) current value in that text box ] and show it in next row. So far I have managed to duplicate the entire data completely to next row. but have no Idea in how to achieve rest. Can any one pint out a solution.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f56b7h9/3/)**

More details from Fiddle: as you can see current value is first text box is `31` if some one changes it to `10` when I duplicate the row to bottom I want that new textbox value to be shown as `21` (which is 31-10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8r8cxcup/

newPalletImte:

```
$scope.newPalletItem = function (palletElement, $event) {
            var npalletElement = {};
            angular.copy(palletElement, npalletElement);
            counter++;

            angular.forEach(npalletElement.Data, function (row) {
                if (row.quantity != row.newquantity) {
                    row.quantity = row.quantity - row.newquantity;
                }

            });

            $scope.palletElement.push(npalletElement);
        };

    });
```

HTML:

```
  <table ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="prdElement in palletElement track by $index">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{prdElement.name}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in prdElement.Data" ng-init="data.newquantity  = data.quantity">
                    <td>{{data.itemId}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.shipmentId}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.itemCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.handlingUnit}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.weight}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.class}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.lenght}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.width}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.height}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.flag}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="data.newquantity" placeholder=" Code" required />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="newPalletItem( prdElement,$event)">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!--<tr id="displayitems">
                    <td>
                        {{palletElement}}
                    </td>

                </tr>-->
            </tbody>
        </table>
```